# Fetching image with curl is smaller than original

Tags: image, file, curl, image-size

I found the problem in some PHP code I'm working on but I can reproduce it using wget and curl, from the linux terminal. When I use the respective programmes to fetch the same image file from my server, the file sizes are different and the smaller curl file is corrupt. This happens on all image files, but doesn't always corrupt the file.

```
0.0.0.0 - - [18/Aug/2013:23:41:48 +0200] "GET /test.png HTTP/1.1" 200 555247 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
0.0.0.0 - - [18/Aug/2013:23:42:53 +0200] "GET /test.png HTTP/1.1" 200 555191 "-" "curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3"
```

You will notice the png file downloaded with curl is 56bytes smaller, which is enough to corrupt the image.
The server in question is my own server running ubuntu server, and apache, as far as I'm aware there is nothing none standard on it, or my curl\wget setup. (And yes I fudged the IP address for security)

Any help most appreciated.

Comment: maybe compressed? try `curl` with option `--compressed`.

Comment: --compressed makes no difference. The "GET /test.png HTTP/1.1" shown in the server logs looks identical, apart from the useragent and size.

Comment: What if you use the option to change the User Agent in both cases? (try the wget one in curl and the other way around)